# How can I remove and re-install a towel rack without destroying the wall?

Tags: bathroom-fixtures

I'm living in a single home rental, so I have to be careful not to damage the walls. Recently, a guest must have grabbed the towel rack to avoid a fall, as it is now pulled away from the wall.

It appears not to be anchored to a stud. The double rack has no set screws so that the rack can be partially disassembled. I can't figure out how this rack comes apart.

Apparently on the opposite wall there is a matching rack. Previous trouble with the rack led someone to install a 3/4" x 5" x 3' board and attach it to studs, so it is well anchored. The matching rack is well anchored to the plywood. I would like to do the same for the one at issue, but I can't figure out how to disassemble it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Or this? [Attaching towel rail to drywall](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/146133/attaching-towel-rail-to-drywall)

Comment: Or this? [How can I fix a towel bar pulled from the wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/251356/35141)

Comment: Or this? [How can I repair a towel rack that was ripped out of the wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/20638/35141)

Comment: And this? **[How to remove this towel bar?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/281193/how-to-remove-this-towel-bar)**

Answer (score 7):

[image](Just lift straight up)
[image]Have you tried sliding the bar to the either side to see if it gives you space to pull the bar out, and then the two holders would unscrew to expose the screws holding it against the wall.

Comment: I got it! I got the horizontal bars out.

I was thinking (from another post below, with a link to a similar unit) that there would be a long screw going through the unit into the wall. But that's not how it works. I could have taken the whole unit down without disassembly if I had known. 

There is a plate attached to the sheetrock with two screws. The plate has two prongs sticking upwards. The unit has a matching plate with two loops that just fiit onto the male prongs. Just by lifting upwards it comes off.
I will post two more photos.

Comment: Yep, and based on those pics, it looks like the mount is screwed to the wall with standard spiral drywall anchors.  You'll need to figure a way to replace at least one of those.  Toggle bolts *may* work for you.

Answer (score 4):

Check the center button of the mount. It will likely "pop" off to reveal a screw that holds the post to a mounting bracket underneath.

Kind of hard to see, but here are [installation instructions](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/14/1469052b-802d-4c98-be35-99d034b1833a.pdf) from, I think, a similar series of models. See "Installation Step 3" specifically. (Unfortunately the written instructions seemed to have not translated to English very well, but the pictures are worth ~1k words still.)

[image: remove center button indicated...]